# request querystring in variable

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

hello iam trying to get the id from a url and send it to the clint side this is what i did

this is my url :

```
http://localhost:53010/edit.aspx?Id=4
```

code behind

```
    Public Partial Class Edit
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Me.Load

End Sub
Private _myId As String = Request.QueryString("id")

Public Property myId() As String
    Get
        Return _myId
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _myId = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class
client

```
<%= myId%>
```

error

```
Request is not available in this context
```

this is also what i get when i move the private prop to page_load() 
   "private " is not valid on local variable declaration –
any idea what is going on

Thanks

---

i solve this problem here is the answer

```
Public Partial Class Edit
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) 
Handles Me.Load
    MyIdVal = Request.QueryString("id")


End Sub

Private _myIdVal As String
Public Property MyIdVal() As String
    Get
        Return _myIdVal
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _myIdVal = value
    End Set
End Property
```

End Class

Comment: You need to learn how VB.Net classes and fields work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a *field initializer*.
Field initializers run before the constructor and cannot access the instance they're initializing.
Therefore, you can't use the `Request` property there.

You need to move that to the constructor or `Page_Load`.

Comment: when i move it to the page load i get this error "private " is not valid on local variable declaration

Comment: You need to move the initialization.

Comment: `myId = Request.QueryString("id")`

Comment: when i do Dim myId As String = Request.QueryString("id") it works fine but as i know i need a property to send myId to the client side right ?

Comment: You need to declare a field in the class, and set its value in `Page_Load`.

Comment: i don't really know how to do this do this

Answer (score 1):

You're accessing the `Request` too early.

It will work if you set `myId` on `Init`, `Page_Load` or any other similar page event.

Comment: Your explanation (first line) is incorrect; this has nothing to do with the page lifecycle.

Comment: when i move it to the page load i get this error "private " is not valid on local variable declaration –

Answer (score 0):

Try to set _myId in your PageLoad.

Comment: when i move it to the page load i get this error "private " is not valid on local variable declaration –

Answer (score -1):

So I wanted a class with properties that were set from querystrings and found this thread. I also wanted to be able to access properties on the front page and even in JavaScript from a single location. Here is what I came up with:

```
// App_Code/QueryStrings.cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

/// <summary>
/// Summary description for QueryStrings
/// </summary>
public class QS
{
    private int id = -1;

    public QS()
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"] != null)
            try
            {
                Int32.TryParse(HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["id"], out id);
            }
            catch
            {
                id = -2;
            }
        else
            id = -3;
    }

    public int ID
    {
    get
        {
            return id;
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call it from your .aspx page as follows:

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <% QS qs = new QS(); %>
        ID = <%= qs.ID %>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Of course you can call from code behind  with the same syntax.

Comment: You are using tryparse (returns bool, does not ever throw) and then catching exception on it. id = -2 will never happen.